# Selecting packages in toctree but not modules

Tags: python-sphinx, glob, toctree

I'm using Sphinx to generate docs for a repository. The Sphinx `toctree` allows the use of `:glob:` to auto-select certain docs.

I have a toctree of the form

```
.. toctree::
     :maxdepth: 1
     :glob:

     _generated/some/repository/structure/*/doc/acme_corp_*
```

where the first `*` gets all of the different modules located in `/some/repository/structure` and I want all the docs from modules that begin with `acme_corp_`.

However, this grabs both packages and modules when the toctree outputs. I've tried using `_generated/some/repository/structure/*/doc/acme_corp_*package` but that outputs no matching links (since I guess that the word `package` does not actually appear in the path).

How can I get Sphinx to auto-generate a `maxdepth: 1` `toctree` such that I only get the packages in the resulting table of contents?

Answer (score 1):

As [a toctree footnotes states:](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/toctree.html#id4)

> A note on available globbing syntax: you can use the standard shell constructs *, ?, [...] and [!...] with the feature that these all don’t match slashes. A double star ** can be used to match any sequence of characters including slashes.

So, it's just a matter of [getting the glob syntax correct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29). If you only want to match on *python packages*, which are folders containing `__init__.py` and other `.py` files, this might work:

```
.. toctree::
     :maxdepth: 1
     :glob:

     _generated/some/repository/structure/*/doc/acme_corp_*/
```

If you want to only match on *python modules*, which are `module_name.py` files, this might work:

```
.. toctree::
     :maxdepth: 1
     :glob:

     _generated/some/repository/structure/*/doc/acme_corp_*.py
```

I can't duplicate this since I don't know your exact project structure, but read up on glob syntax and try different combinations based off of what files/folder patterns you would like to include.